# Rspec output format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

This question is more out of curiosity than purpose. Can we change the output of Rspec command, where it shows dots and Fs. For example, here is an output from one of my projects:

```
.F.F.F.F

.....
........
Finished in 0.27137 seconds
8 examples, 4 failures
```

Can we get Pass Failed Pass Failed Pass Failed Pass Failed instead of .F.F.F.F

Comment: You indeed can, check out https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Formatters or google 'rspec progressformatter' -- here's one that does something very close to what you want: http://www.natontesting.com/2011/04/20/custom-rspec-progress-with-names-formatter/

Comment: @muffinista Thanks!. Can you post that as an answer so that I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed can, check out the [rspec wiki](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Formatters) or google 'rspec progressformatter' -- [here's one](http://www.natontesting.com/2011/04/20/custom-rspec-progress-with-names-formatter/) that does something very close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Color might help a bit - add the alias `spec=spec --color --format specdoc` to your `~/.bashrc` file.